# How can I tell which serial voting episode a reversal is connected to?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, serial-voting

A few days ago I had four posts serial-downvoted, which I suspect was a retaliatory action for some of my editing. I flagged it for a mod, who replied to say they agreed it looked like a serial voting, and that they would pass it onto the Community Managers for assessment.

While that process was in progress, entirely by coincidence, I received another four serial downvotes, at the same loss of rep as before (-8). This may be the same downvoter or an entirely different one.

Finally, earlier today I received a voting correction of +8. However, I can't tell from the UI which of the bouts of voting have been nullified. Either of these things have happened:

- The second set of serial downvotes were automatically reversed, so I am still waiting for the Community Managers
- The Community Managers agreed with the mod report, and actioned a manual reversal, in which case I need to flag one of the most recently downvoted posts, in order to ensure a new CM notification is made

What would be nice in this case is the vote screen indicating *against the actual downvotes themselves* whether they were nullified. This would aid cases where there are several cases of downvoting against the same account. (Of course, whether it is worth the engineering effort for this edge case may be another matter).

Comment: Become a moderator perhaps?

Comment: I too noticed that serial voting did not get auto-corrected.  Mine happened on March 11th.  Good to see they got it working again, disappointing that they didn't consider covering the days that it was inoperative.

Comment: You ~~bribe~~ ask a friendly neighborhood moderator

Comment: Why does it matter which incident it is connected to? You can't do anything about it anyway. All you can do is raise a moderator flag and ask it to be looked into. Since *we* can see this information, that should be sufficient.

Comment: @CodyGray: it matters - though not very much - because it helps me identify the one that still needs reporting. (For this specific case I will wait another day in case there will be a reversal this evening - the question is about the general case, not this specific one).

Comment: @SamuelLiew - righto, I'll get onto that `:=)`

Comment: May I ask how exactly did you flag it? I had a kinda similar issue ~ 5 yrs ago when still a beginner here, and I raised a custom flag which was "*declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*"

Comment: @desertnaut you flagged for multiple votes *on one answer*. That’s not targeted, serial voting, that’s just the community signalling that the answer isn’t helpful to a wider audience. Halfer received a series of votes *on separate posts*, in a very short timespan. The pattern looks like it may possibly have come from a single user targeting halfer, and not the content itself. Multiple votes on an answer are not a single person targeting you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I'm genuinely surprised you can recall the case after all these years. Not the place to discuss the essence, of course, but I have seen answers at -6 since then, and none of them was a functional extension of the answer already provided (with explicit attribution), with 10 lines of code and a comment by the OP "*Thanks! That helps*". I did have an argument a while before with a high rep user in the tag (for the record, he was right), which was one of the voters to delete, and I can imagine a scenario for the rest (although arguably much more difficult to "prove").

Comment: @MartijnPieters and FWIW, I reposted the answer verbatim last year, which now stands with a humble +1 w/o downvotes...

Comment: @desertnaut: I didn't recall anything, I just looked at your flags.